# What method in Java returns the absolute difference of two integers?

Tags: java, integer, absolute-value

Is there a method in the Java `Math` class that returns the absolute difference of two integers?

```
int absDiff = 8 - 15;
int answer = 7;
```

Comment: No, but you can just use `Math.abs()` to turn the difference into an absolute difference.

Comment: Note that the absolute difference between two `int` values may not be expressible as an `int`.  It can be >= 2^31.

Answer (score 5):

There's no method in `java.lang.Math` class that takes 2 int args and returns the absolute difference.
But you can simply do that using the following:

```java
int a = 8;
int b = 15;
int absDiff = Math.abs(a - b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math class abs method like below

```
int num1 = 8; 
int num2 = 15;
int answer = Math.abs(num1 - num2);
```

And You can do this thing by logically also like below

```
int num1 = 8;
int num2 = 15;
int answer = (num1 - num2) * -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers all give the wrong result when the difference is above *Integer.MAX_VALUE*, for example when calculating the absolute difference between 2000000000 and -2000000000 (resulting in 294967296 instead of 4000000000). In that case the correct result cannot be represented by an *int*. The solution is to use *long* for the calculation and the result:

```java
public static long absoluteDifference(int a, int b)
{
    return Math.abs((long) a - b);
}
```

In some situations it's also okay to round down any difference greater than *Integer.MAX_VALUE* to *Integer.MAX_VALUE* (saturation arithmetics):

```java
public static int absoluteDifferenceSaturated(int a, int b)
{
    long absDiff = Math.abs((long) a - b);
    return absDiff > Integer.MAX_VALUE ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Math.toIntExact(absDiff);
}
```

For calculating the absolute difference of two *long*s, you may have to resort to *BigInteger*:

```java
public static BigInteger absoluteDifference(long a, long b)
{
    return BigInteger.valueOf(a).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(b)).abs();
}
```